# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - Need ppa for libdlib-dev

Tags: software-installation

libdlib-dev is not available for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I Need a way to install this.

This package is available for Xenial but not for Trusty http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libdevel/libdlib-dev

Comment: I have no idea what that is...  What is claiming it needs libdliv-dev?

Comment: Do you mean `libdb-dev`? Neither `libdlib-dev` nor `libdliv-dev` seem to exist.

Comment: https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libdlib-dev
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dlib

Comment: There is [this one](https://launchpad.net/~richi-paraeasy/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) but for some reason it calls the package `dlib-dev`, not `libdlib-dev`...

Comment: @fkraiem I was able to install dlib-dev but I was not able to find the .so file.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 64-bit Trusty packages for [`libdlib18`](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/libdlib18_18.18-1build1+trusty1_amd64.deb), [`libdlib-data`](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/libdlib-data_18.18-1build1+trusty1_all.deb), and [`libdlib-dev`](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/libdlib-dev_18.18-1build1+trusty1_amd64.deb) (source packaging [here](http://itsuki.fkraiem.org/stuff/dlib_18.18-1build1+trusty1.debian.tar.gz) but using the one straight from Xenial works too if you're willing to tolerate some lintian warnings). Use at your own risk, etc. No, I cannot provide 32-bit packages.